# Передача количества товаров в paginate_links

Tags: php, woocommerce

Подскажите, допустим на странице категорий товаров есть опция выбора количества товаров, которые должны быть выведены на текущей странице пагинации.
Как передавать это количество между страницами?
Допустим выбрана страница 2 (/page/2). Как нужно передать это количество, выбранное на первой странице? Количество выбирается с помощью списка select.

```
<select name="count_products">
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
</select>
```

Comment: на этом сайте что-то случилось? Несколько тем уже создал, никто не отвечает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сохранять значение count_products (я бы назвал его per_page) в сессию, или добавлять в GET параметр, например /page/2?per_page=4